# Why do mean() and mean(aggregate()) return different results?

Tags: r, aggregate, mean, na

I want to calculate a mean. Here is the code with sample data:

```
# sample data
Nr <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
dph <- c(3.125000, 6.694737, 4.310680, 11.693735, 103.882353, 11.000000, 7.333333, 20.352941, 5.230769, NA, 4.615385, 47.555556, 2.941176, 18.956522, 44.320000, 28.500000, NA, 10.470588, 19.000000, 25.818182, 43.216783, 51.555556, 8.375000, 6.917647, 9.375000, 5.647059, 4.533333, 27.428571, 14.428571, NA, 1.600000, 5.764706, 4.705882, 55.272727, 2.117647, 30.888889, 41.222222, 23.444444, 2.428571, 6.200000, 17.076923, 21.280000, 40.829268, 14.500000, 6.250000, NA, 15.040000, 5.687204, 2.400000, NA, 26.375000, 18.064516, 4.000000, 6.139535, 8.470588, 128.666667, 2.235294, 34.181818, 116.000000, 6.000000, 5.777778, 10.666667, 15.428571, 54.823529, 81.315789, 42.333333)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(Nr = Nr, dph = dph))

# calculate mean directly
mean(dat$dph, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 23.02403

# aggregate first, then calculate mean
mean(aggregate(dph ~ Nr, dat, mean, na.rm = T)$dph)
[1] 22.11743

# 23.02403 != 22.11743
```

**Why do I get two different results?**

---

Explanation for question:

I need to perform a Wilcoxon test, comparing a pre baseline with a post baseline. Pre is 3 measurements, post is 16. Because a Wilcoxon test needs two vectors of equal length, I calculate means for pre and post for each patient with `aggregate`, creating two vectors of equal length. Above data is pre.

Edit:

Patient no. 4 was removed from the data. But using `Nr <- rep(1:22, 3)` returns the same results.

Comment: Does the same happen if Nr contains 4?

Comment: @lawyeR Yes. (I tried with `Nr <- rep(1:22, 3)`.) Just to explain: Patient No. 4 was removed from the data.

Comment: There is no reason you should get the same result. Consider for instance: `Nr<-c(1, 1, 2, 2)` and `dph<-c(1, 2, 3, NA)` and you should realize how you can get different values. Remember that in general the global mean is different from the "mean of the means".

Comment: See e.g. [**here**](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15239/mean-of-means-by-a-factor-versus-global-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because in the `mean(dat$x, na.rm=T)` version, each `NA` that is removed, reduces the number of observations by 1, whereas if you aggregate first, in your example you have an NA in row 10 (ID 11) which is removed but since the other rows with ID 11 do not contain NAs (or at least one of them doesn't), the number of observations (unique IDs) you use to calculate the `mean` *after* aggregation for each ID, is not reduced by 1 for each NA. So the difference IMO comes from dividing the sum of `dph`, which should be the same in both calculations, by different numbers of observations.

You can verify this by changing NA entries to 0 and the calculating the mean again with both versions, they'll return the same.

But generally you should note that it only works here because you have the same number of observations for each ID (3 in this case). If they were different, you would again get different results.